# Cloudformation submitted information does not contain changes when updating task formation image version

Tags: aws-cloudformation

If my cloud formation script is like this:

```
   myServiceName:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::Service"
    Properties:
        ServiceName: "myServiceName"
        TaskDefinition: !Ref  myTaskName
   myTaskName:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
        ContainerDefinitions:
    Image: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/docker-image-name:1.1.1"
```

And I update the task definition to 1.1.2
`Image: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/docker-image-name:1.1.2"`

Then trying to run a Cloud formation update command gives me this error:
*Submitted information does not contain changes. *
Is it just not possible to update the task definition to point to a new image in an ecr with out changing the service?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, could you please double check that the indentation of your YAML code above exactly matches your file? (I suspect your last line should be indented past `ContainerDefinitions`)

Comment: Sorry I just typed up the example real quick, the indention isn't an issue as it would throw a syntax error before it even detected no chnage

Answer (score 0):

All the documentation I've read says that this error comes up when you **don't** change any `properties` of your resource, so Cloudformation doesn't see any resources as changed, and therefore won't redeploy.

But you **are** changing a property, and yet it's still happening, which is weird. I haven't been able to find any record of such behavior.

Debugging suggestion: try adding an arbitrary new property to your resource, e.g. a [tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-tags) field. If it updates successfully, it means for some reason the changed `Image` doesn't trigger an update, and the fix would be to always change something else too. If it still doesn't update, then I suspect something is going wrong somewhere else in your process and you're not actually uploading your changed template at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following in the CloudFormation User Guide that may help.
[Troubleshooting CloudFormation - No updates to perform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-no-updates-to-perform)

I encountered an issue adding a DeletionPolicy attribute (which is not a property). According to the documentation, adding/changing metadata will cause CloudFormation to accept certain changes.